# %_gpg_name not set using maven rpm plugin

Tags: java, maven, cygwin, rpm

We used to distribute rpm packages to deploy our applications. In the last days I had problems signing the rpm.

We need to do it using Maven, so the signature process is fully integrated with our build system.

Maven rpm plugin support the feature to sign rpm using PGP. I set both the parameters `keyname` and `passPhrase`, but the build fail because of:

> You must set "%_gpg_name in your macro file

Since we are in Windows environment I've installed gpg4win version 3.1.3 which works correctly, cywin64 is also installed and working.

Here is a chunk of  my pom.xml where I specify parameters signing rpm

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.5</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>                      
                    <configuration> 
                        <copyright>mycompany</copyright>
                        <group>Mypp</group>
                        <targetOS>Linux</targetOS>
                        <projversion>xxxx</projversion>

                      <keyPassphrase>
                            <passphrase>
                                mypasss
                            </passphrase>
                        </keyPassphrase>
                        <keyname>certName</keyname>

                        <description>description</description>
```

any Idea?

Comment: Are you sure that "certName"  is a useful value? For gpg, the certificate name is ether the keyid or the bound user name. All that rpm does on signing is pass along values to gpg, dunno the maven XML at all.

Comment: in maven rpm plugin U must set the keyname, only setting the key name the signing action is triggered